# Jquery datatable refresh/reload after ajax delete

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

Im doing a maintenance module for comments for my CMS using MVC. This module lists all the comments from all the articles and the user can delete the said comment. I fetch the data using model iteration

```
 @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(item => item.Title))
                {
                    foreach (var item in group.Take(1))
                    {
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6" class="td_accordion">
                                    <table class="tbl-accordion-nested ui fixed single line celled table article_table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="6" class="tbl-accordion-section "><i class="angle down icon"></i> @item.Title </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var items in group)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="artitle_td"></td>
                                                    <td class="comment_td">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.Comment)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.PostedBy)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.CreateDate)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => items.PcName)</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a title="Delete" onclick="validateCancel(@items.ic_id)">Delete</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    }
                }
```

Now, my problem is that, im calling the delete action using ajax post... The delete method works but i can find a way to refresh the datatable without calling this : `document.location.reload(true);`

My function for calling the ajax:

```
function remove(id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Articles/DeleteComment',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                console.log(result);

                },
            complete: function () {
                $('.ui.confirmation.modal').modal('hide');
                $('.ui.button').removeClass('loading');

            }
        })
       document.location.reload(true);
    }
```

Im using JQuery Datatable for SemanticUI

any help would do!

I dont use JSON for the datasource of the datatable

Comment: You have not indicated what the `DeleteComment` returns, but assuming it indicates that the record was deleted (or not), you can just remove the associated row from the DOM - refer [.row().remove()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove())

Comment: Hi, my actionresult is wrote like this: 

 public ActionResult DeleteComment(int? id)
        {
            BigLeaps_Comment bigLeaps_Comment = db.Intranet_BigLeaps_Comments.Find(id);
            db.Intranet_BigLeaps_Comments.Remove(bigLeaps_Comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();


        }

im returning a view... is that wrong? Im not deleting the row in clientside instead using server side

Comment: Your making an ajax call and returning html (a view named `DeleteComment.cshtml`) - just return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise - e.g. `return Json(true);` and then if the result is `true` in the success callback, remove the row from the DOM

Comment: if you are using ajax it means page is not refresh even you are returning view it is not replacing your previous view. so you need to remove that row in success method

Comment: I have returned a json from the actionresult in this manner `return Json(new { result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

now in my ajax, i tried this: `success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        var otable = $('#tbListArticle').DataTable();
                        otable.fnDraw();} }`

but the browser logs that .fnDraw() is not a function... how to delete the row in the dom? can you show me an example?

Comment: FGS. Read the first comment and the link

Comment: Hey @StephenMuecke im not really good at jquery or javascript coding... Im a beginner in both mvc and web application development... would you post an example how to do it? I have tried the links you've given but dont really work as expected.

Comment: Start by removing the `onclick=` from your button and give it a class name and a `data-` attribute - say `class="delete" data-id="@items.ic_id"`.

Comment: Then your script will be `$('.delete').click(function(){ var id = $(this).data('id'); var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // display your confirm then $.ajax({ ..... success: function(result) { table.row(row).remove().draw() } }); });` where `table` is `var table = $('.article_table').DataTable();` (or however you have initialized the plugin.